# Rows of jtextfields with id

Tags: java, swing

Kind of a beginner here so please bear with me.

Here's the situation :
I need to make shopping lists like this :

```
1. Bananas  50   2.25$   Total:
2. Candles  10   3.4 $   Total:
3. Bags     3    0.25$   Total:
```

You get the ideea.
I made an app for android some time ago that did just this,it had everything i needed,sqlite databases,connection with online databases,printing to termal printers,etc, but now i need to make it for desktops.
Now,my ideea,based on what i did on the android app, is this : when the app starts there will be one row with 3 jtextfields and 2 labels. When one of the first textfields is focused,it automatically creates another row.
It also needs to automatically calculate the totals when a textfield is modified.

In android,i created vertical layouts and when the last row was focused,it ran a method to create a new row.Also,when a textfield was modified,it would run the calculus method again and again.

Now,i thought about using jtables but i'm not sure it will be able to do everything i want and also,i think it's easier for the employees to work with textfields then tables.

Could you please tell me what i need to use,to make a plan for me to know what to research ? To guide me a bit ? I forgot a lot from back when i developed for android and i don't know if java can do everything android could.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day !

Comment: Start with [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) I'm sure Swing will allow you to accomplish what you need to.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Swing Components, the java tutorials on Oracle are usually pretty good. Here's the one for `JTable`s:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

I haven't used `JTable`s before, so I don't know them too well, though they look complicated and might mess up your format.

It seems that the TableModel code used for JTable could make the data manipulation and navigation pretty easy to set up. However, it looks like it might be harder to format it like you have and make a well designed GUI (I.E. the total labels on each row should probably be formatted to look uneditable, if you don't just make it a column header).

On the other hand, JTextFields would require you manually code the structure of the data and the navigation code, probably using `Box` or `JPanel` objects. Probably not too hard to figure out, and you can just use the standard ActionListeners and such to update the other cells if you structure it well. It would also be pretty easy to get it to look well-designed.

Either way, I strongly suggest looking through the tutorials on Oracle Swing, they do a good job explaining stuff, and if they don't explain it they'll link to the JavaDocs so you can look there too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.awt.event.FocusListener` to create a new row when a particular textfield is selected  or is focused.

Similarly use `javax.swing.event.CaretListener` to calculate the total as soon as a textfield is modified.

If you're using Netbeans IDE then you can easily add the Listeners using the events tab under properties of a textfield.